# How to exculude data from whereNotIn Clause in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting ahead start working on Bus Management System and I am kind of knew to 
 laravel. 
so here's the **Bus** Table

**[image]**

And this is the **Driver** Table

[image]

So the issue I have faced is that when I am editing the bus, **I want to display drivers that are not in the bus except the editing one**... I mean i want those drivers that have bus not to appear except the one we are are editng.

So i come up with this to make it happen:

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $bus = Bus::find($id);
    $driver = $bus->Driver_id;

    $drivers = Driver::select('*')
                ->whereNotIn('id',function($query) use($driver)  {
                    $query->select('Driver_id')
                    ->whereIn('Driver_id', $driver)
                    ->from('buses');
                })    
                ->get();

  // code here

}
```

Nothing is working fine and.... **And again I want those drivers that have driver_Id in the bus not to retreive except the editing one**.

Comment: So you want to only display drivers that do not have a bus assigned with them? It's a bit hard to understand your question.

Comment: yes it's that but the editing one should be display, since he is has bus assigned. and sorry @Thepeanut

Comment: what's the type of relationship between bus and driver models?

Comment: one to one relationship @Thamerbelfkih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```php
$drivers = Driver::whereRaw('id not in (select Driver_id from buses) OR id = ?', [$bus->Driver_id])->get();
```

It will select any driver that has no bus assigned with it and also the driver from the editing model.

Comment: but is there a way to where clause a station_id, i mean if i want to display drivers of a specif station. and agian thanks

Answer (score 0):

Join will be more preformant than a subquery:

```
Driver::select('driver.*')
    ->leftJoin('bus', 'driver.id', '=', 'bus.driver_id')
    ->whereNull('bus.id')
    ->where('driver.id', '!=', $bus->Driver_id)
    ->get();
```